# How do I get the value from a specific node in an XML file?

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq, xpath, xml-serialization

From this XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Tabel>
  <Member>
    <Naam>Cruciatum</Naam>
    <Kills>1000</Kills>
    <Deaths>10</Deaths>
    <KD>100</KD>
  </Member>
  <Member>
    <Naam>Ghostbullet93</Naam>
    <Kills>10</Kills>
    <Deaths>1</Deaths>
    <KD>10</KD>
  </Member>
</Tabel>
```

How can I get (for example) the 10 next to `<Kills>` ?

I've tried multiple things without any success.
One of the ideas I had was using this code:

```
Dim doc = XDocument.Load("C:\members.xml")
        Dim members = From m In doc.Element("Tabel").Elements("Member")
                      Select naam = m.Element("Naam").Value
        For Each member In members
            lstmembers.Items.Add(member)
        Next
```

But I can't figure out how to edit that snippet to work with what I need it to do now.

(The above code works perfectly for where it's used.)

Comment: League of Legends, or Hamlet?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can also use XPath to read the element's value:

```
Dim doc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
doc.Load("C:\members.xml")
Dim kills As String = doc.SelectNode("Tabel/Member[Naam='Ghostbullet93']/Kills").InnerText
```

If, however, you intend to load and use all the data, it would be far easier to use serialization.  To do that, you first need to create classes that mimic the XML structure (for simplicity sake I'll just use public string fields, but it would be better to use properties):

```
Public Class Member
    Public Naam As String
    Public Kills As Integer
    Public Deaths As Integer
    Public KD As Integer
End Class

Public Class Tabel
    <XmlElement("Member")> _
    Public Members As List(Of Member)
End Class
```

Then deserialize the XML like this:

```
Dim serializer As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(Tabel))
Dim tabel As Tabel = CType(serializer.Deserialize(File.OpenRead("C:\members.xml")), Tabel)
For Each member As Member in tabel
    Dim kills As Integer = member.Kills
Next
```

Comment: @Yorrick I updated my answer with another option using serialization.

Comment: Serialization as in putting it all into 1 row? I'm not quite sure as to what you mean exactly. That being said, the first method works perfectly and quick. It's not like I'll have thousands of `<Member>.</Member>` nodes, only like 20-ish in the end.

Comment: @Yorrick Serialization lets you easily save an object to an XML document.  By default, all the properties of the object are represented in the XML as sub-elements.  You can use attributes to further customize how the serializer formats the XML.  The handy thing is that you can also deserialize from the XML back into an object.  So, if you have some XML that you need to read, you can just create a class that mirrors the XML structure and then deserialize into it.

Comment: @Yorrick I updated the example to show how you could read from the deserialized object.  It will contain a list of all the members.

Answer (score 3):

`XPath` or `XmlDeserialization` a recommended by Steve are excellent options, but for a pure `LINQ` solution, you just need to add an appropriate `Where` clause to your query.

```
Dim doc = XDocument.Load("C:\members.xml")
Dim members = From m In doc.Element("Tabel").Elements("Member")
              Where m.Element("Naam").Value = "Ghostbullet93"
              Select kills = m.Element("Kills").Value
```

`members` will still be an `IEnumerable<String>` in this example, so if you only have 1 object, you need to do something like:

```
Dim member = members.First()  // will throw exception if collection is empty
```

or

```
Dim member = members.Single()  // will throw exception if collection is empty or has 2 or more elements
```

(My vb.NET is extremely rusty, so please forgive any syntax errors).