# Expression is of type "FileName", which is not a collection type

Tags: xml, vb.net, serialization, deserialization

Alright, since I wasn't able to comment and actually ask for help on the original question where I found this I'm making a new one for it (original: [How do I get the value from a specific node in an XML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10725820/how-do-i-get-the-value-from-a-specific-node-in-an-xml-file))

These are two classes I have; One with the structure of my XML file, the second with a list in it:

```
Public Class Member
 Public Naam As String
 Public Kills As Integer
 Public Deaths As Integer
 Public KD As Integer
End Class

Public Class Tabel
 <XmlElement("Member")> _
 Public Members As List(Of Member)
End Class
```

This is the code that executes it:

```
Dim serializer As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(Tabel))
Dim tabel As Tabel = CType(serializer.Deserialize(File.OpenRead("C:\members.xml")), Tabel)
For Each member As Member In tabel
    Dim kills As Integer = member.Kills
Next
```

It should just loop through the xml file and do as it should, but it errors out on "tabel" the last variable in the For Each loop. Saying: Expression is of type 'VBTest.tabel', which is not a collection type.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the `Members` property as a `New` Object or it will error.  Omit `<XmlElement("Member")>` if you what an outer xml element to hold the collection.

```
Public Class Tabel
  '<XmlElement("Member")>
  Public Property Members As New List(Of Member)
End Class
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tebel xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Members>
    <Member>
      <Id>1</Id>
    </Member>
  </Members>
```

If you adding them up then you need the variable outside the loop.

```
Dim kills As Integer
For Each member As Member In tabel.Members
  kills += member.Kills
Next
```

Comment: Well that's what the original idea would've been for the guy who made the original request, but I'm more leaning towards actually going through the list and adding each "series_title" to a listbox or DataTable.

Comment: You could also skip the loop and use `kills = tabel.Members.Sum(Function(m) m.Kills)`

Comment: I went ahead and changed the code to the one you provided and firstly it gave an error for not closing the Property, then it said the New is not valid in this context and I'm still having problems with the collection type error..

Comment: @SythsGod - Your class, `Tabel`, is not a collection type.  It just a normal type that happens to have a collection as one it's properties.  That's why OneFineDay's code uses `tabel.Members` in the For Each.

Comment: I see, happen to have like a good source to learn about using serialization of xml files? Also what I'm trying to do is for each <member> tag in the .xml create a new element in the list.The list contains all the same childs as <member> does, so it's kind of like a structure somehow. (sorry for late response)